# How to solve division query of two differend metrics?

Tags: grafana, prometheus

I have to queries to prometheus at grafana:

First for latency:

```
mtr_latency{quantile=~"$quantile",alias=~"$mtr_endpoint",instance=~"$instance",hop_id=~"$hop_id",hop_ip=~"$hop_ip"}
```

Second for sent packages:

```
mtr_sent{alias=~"$mtr_endpoint",instance=~"$instance",hop_id=~"$hop_id",hop_ip=~"$hop_ip"}
```

How can I solve query to divide of two metrics:

```
(mtr_latency{quantile=~"$quantile",alias=~"$mtr_endpoint",instance=~"$instance",hop_id=~"$hop_id",hop_ip=~"$hop_ip"}/mtr_sent{alias=~"$mtr_endpoint",instance=~"$instance",hop_id=~"$hop_id",hop_ip=~"$hop_ip"})
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have result, but this do not show actual mtr data:

```
(sum(mtr_latency{alias=~"$mtr_endpoint",instance="$instance",hop_id=~"$hop_id",hop_ip=~"$hop_ip"}) by (instance, alias, hop_id, hop_ip))/(sum(mtr_sent{alias=~"$mtr_endpoint",instance="$instance",hop_id=~"$hop_id",hop_ip=~"$hop_ip"}) by (alias,instance,hop_id,hop_ip))
```